# Restkit addFetchRequestBlock does not delete objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, nsfetchrequest, restkit-0.20

I have this piece of code:

```
-(void)fetchCategoriesOnCompletion:(myCompletion) compblock{
    Mapper *mapper = [Mapper new];
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[ASLDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [mapper mapReisCategorie];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/webservice/category/get/apikey/%@/language/%@",apikey,language];

    [objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
        RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"webservice/category/get/apikey/%@/language/%@",apikey,language]];

        NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
        BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];
        if (match) {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Reiscategorie"];
            return fetchRequest;
        }

        return nil;
    }];

    NSURLRequest *request = [objectManager requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:urlString parameters:nil];
    NSLog(@"REQUEST URL IS %@",request.URL);

    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:context success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL success = [context  save:&error];
        if (!success) RKLogWarning(@"Failed saving managed object context: %@", error);
        NSError *saveError = nil;
        compblock(YES);
    } failure:nil];

    [objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

This should delete the objects in core data that I don't get back from the JSON. It used to work but suddenly it doesn't? Has anything changed in restkit?

Comment: The slashes at the start of your path formats don't match, could be an issue. Also, why explicitly create the `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` if you're just going to enqueue it without making any changes?

Comment: @wain could you help me with a little bit of code?

Comment: Change `:@"/webse` to `:@"webse` and retest. Check the block is called. You really need to debug, the code looks fine at a glance.

Comment: @Wain it comes in the block. But does not find a match ?

Comment: Did you log the URL and the pattern to see how they compare?